# Could not find gem 'sdoc (>= 0) ruby'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run my first rails app.  The first error I get is:

```
Could not find gem 'sdoc (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So then I try running "bundle install" and get:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/i18n-0.6.9.gem)
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.6.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.6.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So then I tried "gem install il8n -v '(0.6.9)'" and I get:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'il8n' (= 0.6.9), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

----------------  UPDATE

I then changed

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

After trying bundle install I now get:

```
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So then I try:

```
$ bundle update --source atomic
```

and get

```
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at bit.ly/bundler-issues.
```

Stuck! Any advice is much appreciated.

Charlie

Comment: What do you get when you run "ruby -v" ?

Comment: I have seen this once before, and it was due to a company firewall. Any idea if your internet connection is disallowing certain connections?

Comment: I'm doing this from home, and so I don't think there should be any restrictions.  My ruby v is 2.0.0p247.  Still stuck... would there be any point in uninstalling ruby and rails and trying a complete reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Needed to update Xcode and agree to the new licence.

Answer (score 1):

It works for RubyMine, Ubuntu 14.04x64

replace in your Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Answer (score 0):

replace in your Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

without 's' which mean secure
then

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I now get:    An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I now get - Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!

Comment: try to delete your `Gemfile.lock` file and `$ bundle install` just for make sure

Comment: how do I delete gemfile.lock?

Comment: `$ rm Gemfile.lock` then `$ bundle install`

Comment: It said - rm: gemfile.lock: No such file or directory